# JQuery mobile code won't work on rails 4 app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simple JQuery mobile 'listview' that displays perfectly on a fresh rails 4 app. However, on the application I am currently working I get a blank page.

I made sure to install JQuery mobile on the fresh rails app exactly the same way I installed it on my existing app. Below is my gem file. I can only imagine that there is a conflict. I also have precompiled my assets several times which might have something to do with JQuery code not displaying?

The following line appears in the view source that contains the jquery mobile code, however, the WEbrick development server's output shows that there is not GET for this asset.

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.mobile.js?body=1"></script>
```

**After having installed JQuery mobile there is also a noticeable delay of about 5 seconds before a page loads on the app.**

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'
gem 'aws-s3', :require => "aws/s3"
gem 'foundation-rails'
gem 'rf-rest-open-uri'
gem 'image-picker-rails', '~> 0.1.4.1'
gem 'geokit'
gem 'area'
gem 'sendgrid'
gem 'protected_attributes'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'daemons'
gem "mini_magick"
gem 'stripe'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'rqrcode-rails3'
gem 'rqrcode_png'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery_mobile_rails', '~> 1.4.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

It finally works after uninstalling/reinstalling the gem changing application.js and application.css. Not sure exactly what happened or why it works now.